Why does graphics tablet pressure work for press but not release?
I'm using a Wacom GD-0912-U graphics tablet. I'm running Debian 12.5 and Gimp 2.10.34.
In Gimp, when I touch the pointed end of the pen to the tablet, it registers as a press. But when I lift the pen, the release isn't registered until the pen is about 2.5cm off the tablet.
The eraser end of the pen works fine, however. The release occurs as soon as I lift the pen.
What can I do to make the pointed end work the same way?

Had this issue with another brand of tablet out of the box. Using the firmware provided or app by the manufacturer fixed the issue
